# Coding across the room while walking, possibly using AIDE, TeamViewer, Chromecast, or other mechanism

Tags: 8.1-oreo, android-tv, streaming, accessibility, smart-tv

Why is it that only certain apps can Chromecast to a TV with a Chromecast device? I would like to open AIDE and cast my code onto the television so that I can code on my smartphone as I walk around the room and look at the code on the television. Is it possible to do this? Alternatively, I would like to cast my AIDE code to a laptop or tablet on my desk and let in the keys on my Android smartphone, using it as a keyboard, so that I can type as I walk.

Note, as I code I might only need to view the current line of code on my smartphone and look at the rest of the code on the TV, PC, or tablet, across the room, maybe even sitting down at my desk occasionally.

This way the smartphone is used mainly add an input keyboard for my other devices.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Recently I had also thought of creating a seamless coding system like you.

Comment: May be, this site can help you: https://www.gearbest.com/blog/how-to/use-your-smartphone-as-a-mouse-touchpad-or-keyboard-884

Comment: For the screen casting part, read this page: https://www.airmore.com/mirror-android-screen-tv.html

Comment: These links are great. If I use the Remote Mouse I will need to also mirror my Windows Vista laptop to my television. Not sure if there's a version of Miracast that will install and work on my Windows Vista PC. That way I could use my Android smartphone for input and see the contents of the screen at a distance on my plain but relatively modern non-Android 1080p TV. Any ideas what i would need for this final step? Thanks.

Comment: You can mirror your device screen to a TV/monitor with the Google Home app (uses Chromecast).

Comment: The article @PuspamAdak mentioned states the difference between casting and mirroring. If I use my phone for keyboard input I will need to mirror, not cast, my laptop's desktop. AIDE does seem to support Chromecast at the moment, unfortunately.